# What does 形から入る mean?

Tags: set-phrases, expressions

What does 形から入る mean? What contexts may it be used in? I can't find the phrase in my dictionary.

I ran across this in an anime. Transcription of the relevant parts:

> [麻]{ま}[音]{おん}の父さん　「本当にこの子は『漫画家になりたい』言うたり、『ぬいぐるみの中に入る人になりたい』言うたり、あれはいつだったかな」
>
> 麻音の母さん　「小３の時ですよ、突然…手品師になるからシルクハットとタキシードを買えって言って」
>
> 父さん　「そうだった！とりあえずこの子は[形]{かたち}から[入る]{はいる}からな」
>
> 麻音の友だち１　「ははは…なにそれ？」
>
> 麻音の友だち２　「夢、変わりすぎ！」
>
> 父さん　「まあ、何でもいい。自分で選んだ道だな。麻音が自分自身のなりたいものになればいい」

Translation attempt:

> 'Really, this girl used to say things such as "I want to become
>   a mangaka", "I want to become someone who is inside stuffed
>   animals"... when was that again?'
>
> 'When she was in third grade. She just suddenly demanded a silk hat
>   and a tuxedo because she wanted to become a magician.'
>
> 'That's right. Anyway, she **???**'
>
> '[laughter] What on earth?'
>
> 'Your dreams [of future] are too strange!'
>
> 'Well, anything works for us, if it's a path she's taken by herself.
>   She may become anything she wants to.'

Comment: I found it in the [Denshi Jisho (Beta)](http://beta.jisho.org) dictionary. It's defined as "Mimicking actions of other people (often not understanding the meaning, importance, etc.)." (Direct link to definition [here](http://beta.jisho.org/word/54e9d0d56e733438ac070000).)

Answer (score 8):

Good question.  The phrase would drive me up the wall if I were a Japanese learner, too.

「[形]{かたち}」 here means "appearance".  What that ultimately means is "***outfit***".

「[入]{はい}る」 here means "to start (learning something new)".

I am sure small bilingual dictionaries could be useless with these two in this particular context.

> 「形から入る」 means "Someone (always) starts with the outfit (when taking interest in a new field)."

Fashion over practical training, sorta.

Comment: Is the phrase used outside the context of starting with new things?

Answer (score 2):

You can practice magic if you have cards. A silk hat and a tuxedo are nothing do with magic. You only need them on stage.
So, 「形から入る」 means, buy a complete suite, or more than necessity, before training. If you give up, it's a waste.